# Call a concatenate function into an active cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a concatenate function (`ConcatenateRange`) which works fine on a variable 2 dimension array. I can call this function directly from excel without a problem in the cell required as follows:

```
=ConcatenateRange(B17:E27,"; ")
```

My problem is, I would like this function to be called from the macro instead where the active cell will change. I can get as far as activating the required cell, but cant get it to work, here is what I tried...

```
Cells(CurRow, Col5 + 4).Activate
Call ConcatenateRange(B17:E27, "; ")
```

or

```
Cells(CurRow, Col5 + 4).Activate
Call ConcatenateRange("B17:E27", "; ")
```

but neither work, any help guys?

Kindly

Gurpreet

Answer (score 0):

If you want the formula within the cell you can:

```
 Cells(CurRow, col5 + 4).Formula = "=ConcatenateRange(B17:E27, ""; "")"
```

To just assign as a snapshot you can:

```
Cells(CurRow, col5 + 4).Value = ConcatenateRange([B17:E27], "; ")
```